# How do I set the margins of a centered math expression?

Tags: spacing, equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to globally change the spacing around equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations)

For example,

```
this is a paragraph
\[ \frac{1}{2} \]
this is a paragraph
```

as result, I want something like

```
this is a paragraph


\[ \frac{1}{2} \]


this is a paragraph
```

Comment: Avoid `$$` instead use `\[ ... \]`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to adjust the vertical spacing which is set by the four length parameters

```
\abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip
\belowdisplayskip
\belowdisplayshortskip
```

The default values depend on the current size for example the standard classes define `\normalsize` as

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

so if you go `\setlength\abovedisplayskip{2in plus 1in}` after `\normalsize` you will get more space.

Comment: i dont know why but do not worked. So i used this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations