# Setting vertical space for displayed formula

Tags: spacing, equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to globally change the spacing around equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations)

In a paragraph such as:

```
start text \[ ... \] end text
```

How do you adjust the vertical gap between the text and the formula?

I've tried:

```
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{-5mm}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-5mm}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{-5mm}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-5mm}
```

But this doesn't appear to do anything.

With many thanks.

Comment: Try with `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{-5mm}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-5mm}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{-5mm}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-5mm}}`. I would use rubber lengths.

Comment: Negative values?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `\addtolength` instead of `\setlength`?

Comment: See [How to globally change the spacing around equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations).