# Spurious whitespace in caption

Tags: captions, tex-core, setspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions)

I am not sure what is happening with this MWE.

First the problem: You can clearly see the whitespace between the label and the text of the `caption`.

[image]

The **MWE** given below produces this behaviour.

```
\documentclass{report}

%--- SECTION1-----
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations
\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
  \normalsize
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 3pt}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{3pt plus 2pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 3pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{3pt plus 2pt}
}

%-----SECTION2-----
\usepackage{setspace}

%-----SECTION3-----
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
  textfont={singlespacing},
}
%------------------
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{2cm}
    \caption{Application of ICA for two sources with Gaussian distribution}
    \label{fig:icaDistributions}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The preamble is separated in three sections. The code in section-1 for setting various lengths is from [how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations). As far as I understand it, the lengths will be defined each time `\normalsize` is defined/changed. Since we are setting these lengths to constants, the change in fontsize won't affect these lengths. Since various people have recommended this method, I am assuming this is a good practice.

Here are some observations:

1. If any one of the sections are commented out, then the white space
   disappears.
2. If section-1 is modified by adding comment mark `%` at
   the end of these lines then the whitespace disappears.
3. In fact, each line with `setlength` is adding a whitespace after the label in `caption`.

> ```
> \expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
>   \normalsize
>   \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 3pt}%
>   \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{3pt plus 2pt}%
>   \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 3pt}%
>   \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{3pt plus 2pt}%
> }
> ```

The questions are:

1. Is the method of setting lengths correct?
2. Why does the spurious space disappear when `setspace` package is not used?
3. Why does the spurious space disappear when `singlespacing` option from package `caption` is not used?
4. Why does the spurious whitespace disappear when `%` is added at the end of the `setlength` command lines?

I would like to know what is happening here and what is the correct way of handling this problem.

Comment: It is the end of line character. Search in this site for answers. For example [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946) and links provided in that question's comments.

Comment: @HarishKumar - in that case, the whitespace should still be there when package `setspace` is not used.

Comment: A whitespace does not always make harm, e.g. it does make harm when TeX is in horizontal mode but does not make any harm when TeX is in vertical mode. If the caption option `singlespacing` is used and the `setspace` package is loaded, `\setstretch{1}` will be used prior typesetting the caption, and this will call `\normalsize` in TeX`s horizontal mode.

Comment: Regarding Question 2: If the `setspace` package is not loaded the caption option `textfont=singlespacing` simply does nothing. (See caption3.sty how the font setting `singlespacing` is defined.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt - This looks like an answer. So the moral of the story is that a whitespace left unattended might be dangerous in certain situations which might or might not arise depending on how/which packages are loaded. So to be on safe side, always remove whitespaces. Is there a way to make `latex` give me errors whenever I have left an unintended whitespace? (something like strict compilation rules)

Comment: @devendra Not really: whitespace is entirely sensible in a typesetting system!