# How to add a line break

Tags: line-breaking

Sometimes I need an empty line like this

[image]

If I write

```
$\Rightarrow \mathcal{I}_1 = \{\{A\}, \{B\}, \{C\}, \{E\}\}$
\\
Generierung der häufigen $2$-Itemsets:
```

I'll get an error "There's no line here to end".

So, I've made

```
$\Rightarrow \mathcal{I}_1 = \{\{A\}, \{B\}, \{C\}, \{E\}\}$
$ $\\
Generierung der häufigen $2$-Itemsets:
```

This works, but I want to use a nicer solution...

How can I fix this??

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure you really want an “empty line”; probably you want that the equation is displayed, that is, set in `\[...\]`. “Empty lines” are mostly a consequence of using word processors, but they're rarely a good typographical device.

Comment: As @egreg says, you never (as in 99%) need manual line breaks in running text. Instead learn to use displayed math when appropriate. IMO it is a mistake that users learn that ` \\ ` and `\newline` can be used in the normal text. They almost always get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the equation in a `displaymath` or `equation` environment to create space before and after the equation.

```
\begin{displaymath}
 1+1=2 
\end{displaymath}
```

How to adjust the spacing around an equation has been treated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations).

If this question does not only refer to space after equations but skipping one line in general, maybe `\vspace{\baselineskip}` will serve your needs. This should generate vertical space in the size of one standard line of text.