# Reduce vertical blank space between centered mathematical phrases and normal text

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

When I use $$$$ for mathematical text, there is too much vertical blank space between the mathematical text and the main text. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: if you have a blank line before the display remove it (there should never be a blank line before display math) also, if using latex you should use `\[` not `$$`. Otherwise you need to show an example to give more of a hint about the problem

Comment: this may help: [How to globally change the spacing around equations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69662)