# How to avoid the indentation made by \**displayskip?

Tags: math-mode, equations, documentclass-writing

I wrote a class file, but I found if I want to change the space between the math environment and text by the [solution provided by Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations), the indentation appears in front of the 'abstract'. Here is the mwe,

```
            \begin{filecontents}{mycls.cls}
            \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
            \ProvidesClass{mycls}
            \LoadClass{article}
            \newdimen\@bls
            \@bls=\baselineskip
            \renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {1.2\@bls  plus .3\@bls minus .1\@bls}%
                                   {5pt\@afterindentfalse}%
                                   {\sffamily\large\bfseries\raggedright}}
            \newbox\absbox
            \def\abstract{\lrbox\absbox\minipage{\textwidth}%
            \sffamily%
            \hspace{-\fill}\section*{\normalsize\noindent Abstract}\vskip -1.5mm\relax%
            }
            \def\endabstract{\endminipage\endlrbox}

            \def\keywords#1{%
            \gdef\@keywords{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\normalsize\sffamily \textbf{Keywords}}\\ \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{#1}\end{minipage}}}
            \let\@keywords\@empty

            \def\@maketitle{{\noindent\usebox\absbox\par}
            {\vspace{20pt}%
            {\noindent\normalsize\@keywords}\par}{\vskip2em\relax}}
            \end{filecontents}
            \documentclass{mycls}
            \usepackage{lipsum}
            \begin{abstract}
            \lipsum[1]
            \end{abstract}
            \keywords{Hello}
            \begin{document}
            \maketitle
            \lipsum[1]
            \begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
            a^2+b^2=c^2
            \end{equation}
            \lipsum[1]
            \end{document}
```

The class and code above gives 
[image]

But if I add the code

```
            \expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
                \normalsize
                \setlength\abovedisplayskip{40pt}
                \setlength\belowdisplayskip{40pt}
                \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{40pt}
                \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{40pt}
            }
```

in the class file, the output will be

[image]

Some space appears in front of the 'abstract' and 'keywords'.

I want to know where the space comes from and how to cancel it.

Comment: First of all, you should use proper LaTeX, no TeX constructs.

Comment: [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)

Comment: Also, don't call `\normalsize` in its own definition and provide a proper size for `normalzise`.

Comment: Thansk for your comments. The code is copy from a class file written by a publisher and I want to modify it.

Comment: `{5pt\@afterindentfalse}%` is wrong, that argument should be a positive or negative length. And there are lots of `%` missing from ends of lines so they will generate spaces in your output. every use of `\normalsize` as defined above will add 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @DavidCarlisle. It helps me a lot.

Comment: I reads the links you provide, the information in that is useful. Thanks :) @Johannes_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{5pt\@afterindentfalse}%` is wrong, that argument should be a positive or negative length. And there are lots of `%` missing from ends of lines so they will generate spaces in your output. every use of `\normalsize` as defined above will add 4 spaces.

```
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
                \normalsize
                \setlength\abovedisplayskip{40pt}%%one space
                \setlength\belowdisplayskip{40pt}%% one more
                \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{40pt}%% a third
                \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{40pt}%% a fourth
            }
```