# Changing displayskips glitches titleps

Tags: spacing, header-footer, titleps

I'm using `titleps` for my masters thesis. When I change the displayskips as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/how-to-globally-change-the-spacing-around-equations) the headings become offset. Without using rubber spacing the headings are only minimally offset. I would really appreciate some advice, please.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%%%%%%%%SPACING%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\apptocmd\normalsize{
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{.1cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}}{}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PAGESTYLES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}[\small]{
\setheadrule{.3pt}
\sethead[Chapter \thechapter][][]
{}{}{\thesection \, \sectiontitle}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]
{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document} 
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: I don't see the problem. Is it the widow at the top of the second page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modification to the code for `\normalsize` is adding extra spaces in the output, one for each newline in the code.  You need to comment out these end of lines using `%` characters as follows

```
\apptocmd\normalsize{%
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{.1cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}}{}{}
```

See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/15925) for related discussion.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%%%%%%%%SPACING%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\apptocmd\normalsize{
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{.1cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{.5cm plus .1cm minus .1cm}}{}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PAGESTYLES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}[\small]{
\setheadrule{.3pt}
\sethead[Chapter \thechapter][][]
{}{}{\thesection \, \sectiontitle}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]
{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document} 
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```